# use wildcard in solr facet query search

Tags: solr, facet

How to search for a word in facet query in solr (or in other words how to use wildcard in search by facet)
for example
if i have facet filed **MyField** and it has the following values:

```
ValX ValY
ValX
ValZ ValW
ValX ValV
ValA ValX
ValA ValB
```

now if i search for `fq=MyField:ValX`, i will get the second record only. how can i search for ValX and get the 1st, 2nd, 4th and 5th records?
you know `fq=MyField:*ValX*` is not allowed and `fq=MyField:ValX*` will not return the 5th record.
any idea is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is this not supported by SOLR fq=MyField:*ValX*? If so how it can be achieved ? i want to filter based on a matching text like \*text\*. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wildcard card on Facet Query should work](http://blog.shutupandcode.net/?p=1425).

As wildcard queries does not undergo any analysis, you can try `fq=MyField:valx*`

What you are trying is not filtering but rather searching.
Use a white space tokenizer with lower case filters and search `q=MyField:valx` and it would match the results. You can use prefix and wildcard queries with it as well.

Comment: Thanks, but this wouldn't return the fifth record.... how can i return valx regardless of its position (???ValX???)

Comment: Refered link is broken

Answer (score 2):

How is MyField defined in schema.xml? Looks to me as if it isn't tokenized, like for instance with

```
type="string"
```

With

```
type="text"
```

the field value is tokenized so that

```
fq=MyField:valx
```

should match 1, 2, 4 and 5.